# Is it legal to use #define in order to define the size of a static array?

Tags: c++, dynamic, c-preprocessor, static-array

I have many classes in the system that I'm currently developing and in these classes I have an array about the "name" of something. The name should be at most 30 characters.

Initially I used just 10 characters but now I need to increase the limit. Increasing the limit takes time though because I use this kind of array in many places. It would be easier if I used `#define NAME_SIZE 30` or something like that and then all I would have to do is change one number instead of around twenty.

However I'm not sure if that's a "legal" thing to do in C++.

It would save me tons of time in the future, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have many instances of "magic numbers" in your code. That is far worse than using `#define` could ever be for the exact reasons you stated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing technically wrong with it, except that `#define` is usually inferior to a `const std::size_t MAX_NAME_SIZE = 30;` Even better would be to have a dynamic size, e.g. using `std::string`.

Scott Meyers has an interesting column about systems that use gratuitous fixed sizes, called [The Keyhole Problem](http://www.aristeia.com/TKP/draftPaper.pdf)

> The Keyhole Problem arises every time software **artificially restricts**
>   something you want to see or something you want to express. If you
>   want to see an image, but your image-viewing software artificially
>   restricts how much of that image you can see at a time, that’s the
>   keyhole problem. If you want to specify a password of a particular
>   length, but your software says it’s too long, that’s the keyhole
>   problem. If you want to type in your U.S. telephone number, but your
>   software refuses to let you punctuate it in the conventional manner
>   with a dash between the three-digit prefix and the four-digit
>   exchange, that’s the keyhole problem.

Apart from annoynance from users, you also open your systems to all sorts of security issues (e.g. buffer overflow exploits).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's legal. But it's generally preferable to use actual constants instead of macros:

```
const int max = 30;
char blah[max];
```

Another alternative is to use a `std::string` and not have an hard-coded limit (following the [zero-one-infinity rule](http://catb.org/jargon/html/Z/Zero-One-Infinity-Rule.html)).

Comment: I believe that `size_t` would be a more appropriate type for the constant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is legal, but you might want to use a `const int NAME_SIZE = 30;`. This can be safely put in a header file. Unlike non-const global variables, having const variables in different translation units (cpp files) creates no problems for linker, since each constant is local to a file it's defined in.